# PostgreSql Rectangle DataType for storing Left, Top, Width and Height

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to store a rectangle inside a table.

At the moment i have 4 seperate columns:

- top
- left
- width
- height

I noticed that PostgreSql offers a datatype called [box](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-geometric.html).

However this datatype automatically reorders the values based on:

> Any two opposite corners can be supplied on input, but the values will be reordered as needed to store the upper right and lower left corners, in that order.

I tried using the box datatype for rectangles but as stated it sometimes mixes upperright and bottomleft, so it is not suitable for storing top, left, width and height.

I am writing a C# application that handles those values. Therefore it would be nice if i have a datatype that is equivalent to the C# Rectangle type.

I am wondering how to implement a rectangle / rect datatype. Maybe even write an own datatype based on four integers (array[4])?

Comment: What does not work with your current solution?

Comment: @Renzo It mixes the values based on lowerleft and upperright - annoying when dealing with negative values inside the rectangle. Also i can't convert it to the native C# Rectangle type. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mix the points, it stores them with the top right values first. You will just have to read out these and work out the other 2 points yourself if you need them.

That's not exactly complicated stuff - at the least you can read the top/right point and take the top value, and the bottom/left point and take the left point to obtain the top/left point you want. Similarly, reading width is just right minus left.

Comment: I am writing a C# application that handles those values. Therefore it would be nice if i have a datatype that is equivalent to the C# Rectangle type. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: if the co-ordinate origin in bottom left of the screen, then it makes a lot of sense from an optimised indexing mechanism to store the 2 biggest numbers together. You'll have to write a facade in your C# code to convert, or replace your Rects with a new c# datatype.

Comment: Thank you for this knowledge. It saved me some work. I need to store croping coordinates for pdf croping. PDFs has origin at bottom left, and I need to provide croping coordinates in the order <bottomLeft, topRight>. If "box" reorders these I'll be better off with two "point" fields instead. I'll read up some more on the datatypes.